# NGINX How to rewrite a pathname but not files?

Tags: nginx

I have a NGINX server that serves a UI at `/`. The UI is running on localhost:8081 and the server runs on localhost:8080.

I need any pathname that is entered to be passed to the root of the UI.

For example:

`localhost:8080/search` should proxy_pass to `localhost:8081`

but files should not be changed:

`localhost:8080/main.css` => `localhost:8081/main.css`

---

**This works but isn't dynamic**

I tried to use a separate location for each pathname however I want the configuration to be dynamic for future development.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}

location /search {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
}

location /foobar {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
}
```

**File name handler**

I tried catching the file names but you can't proxy_pass within a regex location block.

```
location ~* \.(.*?)$ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
}
```

**try_files**

I tried using `try_files` but nginx didn't serve anything (gave me a prompt to set up nginx)

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ @app;
}

location @app {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
}
```

---

My Nginx config looks like this without the location blocks

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log   /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/error.log notice;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format main '[$time_local] $remote_addr - "$request" '
        '$status "$http_referer" => "$proxy_host" $uri';
    log_format log_server escape=json '$request_body';

    access_log  /usr/local/etc/nginx/logs/access.log  main;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
    proxy_buffering off;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;
        rewrite_log  on;

        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';

        location / {
            # stuff from above + headers
        }
    }
}
```

I am using webpack dev server for local development however the final bundle has the structure:

```
/root
  bundle.js
  main.css
  index.html
  cd6c777f1945164224dee082abaea03a.woff2
  etc...
```

Comment: By "files" you mean any path that contains a dot? So a path with a dot should be proxied intact, but a path without a dot should be proxied to the root of your dev server, correct?

Comment: Why do you say `proxy_pass` can't be used within a regex `location` block?

Comment: @KyleFransham yes exactly

Comment: @CalumHalpin Nginx gave me an error when I tried to run `nginx -t` saying its not allowed in there

Comment: Could you post the error? According to the [docs](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) it is permitted.

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:53`

Comment: You could just use: `rewrite ^/[A-Za-z]+$ / last;`

Comment: See this post: https://serverfault.com/questions/649151/nginx-location-regex-doesnt-work-with-proxy-pass 

looks like you might just have to eliminate the trailing slash from your localhost:8081 route

Comment: @RichardSmith That works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @KyleFransham In testing all of this I added a / to the end. Ive tried with and without a / and thats definitely not the issue.